# Constrained extrema and geometric interpretation of constrained stationary points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, constraints, implicit-function

I'm studying constrained extrema for functions of two variables and with a single constraint(of equality).
So I have a function $f$ and I have to find its constrained extrema in the restriction $E_0=\{(x,y)|g(x,y)=0\}$ where $f,g:A\subseteq \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $ and $f,g \in C^1(A)$ (where $A$ is open).
If $g(x_0,y_0)=0$ and $\nabla g(x_0,y_0)\neq 0$(in this case the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is called regular), by implicit function theorem I can parametrize $E_0$ in a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$, so let's call this curve $\gamma:\mathbf{r}(t)$ (Without loss of generality $\mathbf{r}(0)=(x_0,y_0)$) .  A constrained stationary point is regular point  such that $(f \circ  \mathbf{r})'(t)=0$. Clearly this is equivalent to $\langle \nabla f(x_0,y_0),\mathbf{r}'(0) \rangle=0$. Then my book says that this is equivalent to the fact that "the derivative of $f$ along the direction that is tangent to $E_0$ in $(x_0,y_0)$ is $0$". I think that the book used the fact that:
$$ \langle \nabla f(x_0,y_0),\mathbf{r}'(0) \rangle=D_{\mathbf{r}'(0)} f(x_0,y_0)=0 $$
But this is valid iff $\mathbf{r}'(0)\neq \mathbf{0}$. How do we know that?
If $\mathbf{r}'(0)= \mathbf{0}$, then it doesn't correspond to a direction.
This is giving me many difficulties. Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**
Now that I think about it the geometric intepretation of $\mathbf {r}'(t)$ is the tangent vector in $\mathbf{r}(t)$ to the curve $\gamma$, what would it mean if $\mathbf{r}'(t)=0$, geometrically.

Comment: I guess $A$ is a rather good (for instance, open) subset of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky What do you mean?

Comment: Both for the definition of $C^1(A)$ and the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), we need functions $f$ and $g$ to be differentiable at points of $A$.As far as I know, usually for a function to be [differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) at a point, the function should be defined at some neighborhood of the point. This holds when the domain of the function is open.Or you know a stronger version of the implicit function theorem, which can be applied to a non-interior point $(x_0,y_0)$ of a domain of the function $g$?

Comment: Yes the domain is open but how this affects $\mathbf{r}'(0)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course assume ${\bf r}'(0)\ne{\bf 0}$. This comes from the implicit function theorem:

When $\nabla g(x_0,y_0)\ne{\bf 0}$ you have, e.g., $g_y(x_0,y_0)\ne0$. This implies that there is a   window $$W:=[x_0-h,x_0+h]\times[y_0-h,y_0+h]\subset{\mathbb R}^2$$ and a $C^1$ function
$$\psi:\quad[x_0-h,x_0+h]\to[y_0-h,y_0+h],\qquad x\mapsto y=\psi(x);\qquad\psi(x_0)=y_0,$$
such that the set $\bigl\{(x,y)\in W\bigm| g(x,y)=0\bigr\}$ coincides with the graph of $\psi$. This implies that you can take
$$\gamma:\quad[x_0-h,x_0+h]\to W, \qquad x\mapsto {\bf r}(x):=\bigl(x,\psi(x)\bigr)\qquad(x_0-h<x<x_0+h)$$
in your proof. Here ${\bf r}'(x)=(1,\psi'(x))\ne{\bf 0}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! And could you also explain me what’s the geometrical meaning of  the derivative of a function$\mathbf{r}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ being $0$ at a point, as I ask in the edit.

Comment: @Eureka: It means that this particular parametrized curve cannot be used in the proof. All we need is that for each tangent vector ${\bf v}\ne{\bf 0}$ we can find a curve $t\mapsto{\bf r}(t)$ having ${\bf r}'(0)={\bf v}$.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I'm not asking about the proof. I'm asking about the "geometrical meaning" of having the derivative of a parametrized curve equal 0 in a point. Since it usually represents the tangent vector in that point.